# How to filtering information on the second page based on data on the first page in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5, abap

I have a table. The first field of this table contains ID data.
[image]

When I click the marked button, I go to the second page. And this page has a few tables below as well.
[image] Like this...

I get ID data in the background while adding data to the second table.
[image]

All of the tables have different IDs. When I go to the second page, I want the fields with the same ID to appear.

For example, when I click on the line with ID 000001, ENG with ID 1 should appear on the second page.

I applied such a filter for this but it didn't work:

```
onPress: function (oEvent) {
            // The source is the list item that got pressed
            this._showObject(oEvent.getSource());


            var sFilterData = this.getView().getModel("kisiselBilgiler").getData();//first table json model id
            var aFilter = [];
            aFilter.push(new Filter("perId", FilterOperator.EQ, sFilterData.Id));
            var oBinding = this.getView().byId("lisanTable").getBinding("items"); //second table id
            oBinding.filter(aFilter);
        },
```

My kisiselBilgiler Json Model in Worklist.controller.js:

```
 onInit: function () {
            // <<<<<<<<< KİŞİSEL BAŞLANGIÇ
            var kisiselData = {
                Id: "",
                İsim: "",
                dTarih: yeni Tarih (), 
                Posta: "",
                isAdrc: "",
                Hakkinda: "",
                Lisans: "",
                Uyruk: ""
            };
            var oModel = new JSONModel (kisiselData);
            this.getView (). setModel (oModel, "kisiselBilgiler");
}, ...
```

The table I want to bind in Object.view.xml:

```
<Table id="lisanTable" width="auto" items="{ path: '/lisanSet', sorter: { path: 'perId', descending: false }, filters: [{path: 'perId'}] }"
                            noDataText="{worklistView>/tableNoDataText}" busyIndicatorDelay="{worklistView>/tableBusyDelay}" growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true"
                            updateFinished=".onUpdateFinished">
                            <columns>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{i18n>perLisan}"/>
                                </Column>
                            </columns>
                            <items>
                                <ColumnListItem>
                                    <cells>
                                        <Text text="{perLisan}"/>
                                    </cells>
                                </ColumnListItem>
                            </items>
                        </Table>
```

My error:
[image]

How can I do it?

**NOTE:** Github link of the project: https://github.com/shrgrl/CVApp

Comment: The question has some answers in [SAP Community](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13142369/a-table-without-a-header-line-and-therefore-has-no.html) too.

Answer (score 3):

That FM is expecting a single field, not a table column.  You need to loop at lt_mbbez and pass a single record value into that FM at a time.

```
loop at lt_mbbez assigning field-symbol(<mbbez>). 
   CALL FUNCTION 'C14Z_MESSAGES_SHOW_AS_POPUP'
     EXPORTING
       i_msgid  = 'ZSG_INFO_MSG'
       i_msgty  = 'I'
       i_msgno  = '000'
       i_msgv1  = <mbbez>-mbbez
       i_lineno = 1.
endloop.
```

The error message is funky because once upon a time you could declare a table with an implicit header line, and it would have the same name as the table (well you still can in some contexts, but you shouldn’t).

Comment: Just nitpicking about the term "work area". It's used in the ABAP syntax for naming generically a data object when it's used to transfer data from or to an internal table, when the type of lines of the internal table is not important to mention -could be elementary, structure, nested internal table- for instance `LOOP AT itab INTO work_area`. You are talking about the [**header line**](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenheader_line_glosry.htm), which can be used as an implicit work area.